# Macports Install Error

Tags: macos, valgrind, macports

I am installing Valgrind using macports and getting the following error:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for valgrind
--->  Building valgrind
Error: org.macports.build for port valgrind returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port valgrind for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port valgrind failed
```

Here is the log file:

```
:notice:build --->  Building valgrind
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (valgrind)
:debug:build Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1" && /usr/bin/make -w all'
:debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1" && /usr/bin/make -w all 
:info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1'
:info:build /usr/bin/make  all-recursive
:info:build make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1'
:info:build Making all in include
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/include'
:info:build make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/include'
:info:build Making all in VEX
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
:info:build /usr/bin/make  all-am
:info:build make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
:info:build make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
:info:build make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/VEX'
:info:build Making all in coregrind
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/coregrind'
:info:build (cd m_mach && mig /usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs /usr/include/mach/task.defs /usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs /usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs)
:info:build 
:info:build You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 'xcodebuild -license' (for user-level acceptance) or 'sudo xcodebuild -license' (for system-wide acceptance) from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.
:info:build /usr/bin/mig: line 174: : command not found
:info:build mig: fatal: "<no name yet>", line -1: no SubSystem declaration
:info:build make[2]: *** [m_mach/mach_vmUser.c] Error 1
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1/coregrind'
:info:build make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/work/valgrind-3.8.1" && /usr/bin/make -w all 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port valgrind returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 41934 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
    invoked from within
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for valgrind: org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:build Please see the log file for port valgrind for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_valgrind/valgrind/main.log
```

I already have Valgrind installed (3.7, older version). Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the log, one of the errors you are getting is that you haven't accepted the license agreement for Xcode's command line tools. To do this, type `xcodebuild -license` into Terminal.